# Force Spring security to check credentials before account status flags

Tags: java, spring-security

I've subclassed org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User and in my constructor I call:

```
Super (String username,
        String password,
        boolean enabled,
        boolean accountNonExpired,
        boolean credentialsNonExpired,
        boolean accountNonLocked,
        GrantedAuthority[] authorities)
```

I then use `${SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION.message}` to display the result when login fails.

The problem I have is that if I set accountNotLocked to false then the account locked error message is displayed and this happens whether or not the password is correct. I would far prefer it if spring validated credentials first and then enabled, accountNonExpired, credentialsNonExpired and accountNonLocked flags. This way a user would only be notified that their account was locked if they got the credentials right.

Is there a way to force spring to do this?

Comment: ideally i would suggest not to do this as it is better to check flag first instead of password (as this can be used to guess correct password)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you're using most popular [`DaoAuthenticationProvider`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/authentication/dao/DaoAuthenticationProvider.html) and that the problem is in [`UserDetailsChecker`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetailsChecker.html) default implementations in this class. That said, moving all checks after `DaoAuthenticationProvider.additionalAuthenticationChecks` should be enough to solve your problem. Try following config:

```
<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
  <authentication-provider ref="daoAuthenticationProvider" />
</authentication-manager>

<bean id="daoAuthenticationProvider"
      class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
  <property name="userDetailsService" ref="userDetailsService"/>
  <property name="passwordEncoder" ref="passwordEncoder"/>
  <property name="preAuthenticationChecks"
      class="com.example.NullUserDetailsChecker"/>
  <property name="postAuthenticationChecks"
      class="org.springframework.security.authentication.AccountStatusUserDetailsChecker"/>
</bean>
```

where `com.example.NullUserDetailsChecker` is [null object pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern) implementation of `UserDetailsChecker` (has void check method which does nothing).